# fs.js module in nodejs requiring itself?

Tags: node.js

I'm currently learning nodeJS and running version v6.10.2, I was taking a look at the fs.js module source code located in the graceful-js folder and noticed this code in it:

```
'use strict'

var fs = require('fs')

module.exports = clone(fs)

function clone (obj) {
  if (obj === null || typeof obj !== 'object')
    return obj

  if (obj instanceof Object)
    var copy = { __proto__: obj.__proto__ }
  else
    var copy = Object.create(null)

  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    Object.defineProperty(copy, key, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key))
  })

  return copy
}
```

How can a module require itself does it have to do with the clone keyword? I couldn't find any other module named fs.js either.

Comment: This is not the built-in `fs` module requiring itself.  This is the graceful-fs replacement module requiring in the actual `fs` module.

Comment: The code for the actual fs module is here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js

Comment: @jfriend00 I could not find the actual fs module in my installed nodejs folder, how does the graceful-fs module require it?

Comment: It's built in, not a separate file.  Easier to find the built in code on github or step into it in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at part of the code for the [`graceful-fs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graceful-fs) package which is a wrapper around the builtin [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module in NodeJS. So this code is not requiring itself - the require statement imports the builtin `fs` module and the rest of the code clones it so that other parts of the `graceful-fs` package can override some of the default `fs` functionality without affecting the original module.

Comment: What is the graceful-fs package used for?

Comment: From the [package homepage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graceful-fs) I linked to: "graceful-fs functions as a drop-in replacement for the fs module, making various improvements. The improvements are meant to normalize behavior across different platforms and environments, and to make filesystem access more resilient to errors."